# Howto to associate a progressdialog with a service in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a sync service using `AsyncTask`. Due to its objective (sync), I prefer to block the user and show him a progressdialog. (And error if exists)

Another difficulty is that I have about 8 `AsyncTask` running simultaneously. So I can't do a simple call to the progress dialog page when I begin the work and a close when it's finished. It's more complex.

Can someone help me with that task ?

Regards

Comment: what do you mean by service exactly? are you actually running a service, or do you have a component in your activity that performs these tasks?

Comment: I have a class which inherits from android Service. When launched that service call asyntask (json web service) and when there is an answer, the asynctask call back a service function. That function call the right function (FillUsers for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place the point of the Service is that you don't need/want to block user to do stuff because it happens in the background. To that aspect, a Service doesn't have a UI thread, so if you want a progress bar shown in your Activity you'll have to send an Intent back to your activity (using broadcast receivers), such that you can switch the progress bar on/off and do other magic.

I would not recommend blocking the user though, because the tasks you are doing might take a very long time, giving a nasty user experience. You might even want to reconsider using a Service at all (if the data you are fetching is only used locally; for example fetch the latest twitter messages or something) and just go with an ASyncTask in your Activity, unless the data your Service fetches is used in other parts of your app as well (widgets for example) and you want that data available even if the activity isn't running.

Comment: well the data synced are mandatory for my application. It is a business application and I want to sync data like customers and if the user select user and if that user is hidden. There can be some strange behaviour. I don't remember why I used a service, there was something which didn't work and maybe it would work now ... In my case, I want two major feature 1) say to the user when the sync is finished 2) say if there is a failure (please try again)

Comment: In that case you have to let the service inform the activity that the sync has finished/fail by means of an intent broadcast which the activity can receive by means of intent filter or specific broadcast receiver, or perhaps show a notification in the android notification bar.

Answer (score 2):

`onPreExecute()`, `onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` and `onPostExecute(Result)` in AsyncTask are invoked on the UI thread. You can use these to display a progress bar, update it as the syncing progresses and hiding it when the work is finished.

As to the 8 simultaneous async tasks, do you really need 8 concurrent tasks? Can't you run them sequentially on one background thread using a single AsyncTask?

Comment: well the asynctask is called by the service. Can a service call a progress dialog or is it limitated on the activity ? And the 8 simultaneous tasks aren't needed, I'm rewriting the code ...

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [progress dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) to show wait cursor kinda thing.
Also you can imitate the concept of [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in your application to dismiss the cursor. Like you can have a static function in a class like updateTaskComplete and update a static counter. And once the counter is equal to number of async task then in the function updateTaskComplete cancel the progress cursor. I mean you have to do something on this line.